# How to get UIScrollView to scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift

I have been trying to get a UIScrollView to scroll, I made the content size larger than the view, yet it does't scroll.  I can enable bounceVertical, and that works fine.

```
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 320,height: 420)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 320,height: 568)
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Why won't the scroll view scroll?

Edit:

This code works fine, auto-layout needs to be disabled to change the content size of a scroll view.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout and storyboards?

Comment: Using storyboards, not auto-layout.  The scroll view is attached to a scroll view in the storyboard.  It is defined: `@IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView`

Comment: which iOS version are you testing on? iOS 8 yes?

Comment: Yes, iOS 8 on Xcode-6 Beta 1

Comment: Try upgrading to Beta 2. That code seems to work just fine.

Comment: Are you doing anything else with that scrollView?

Comment: I disabled auto-layout in the storyboard file, and that made it work.  Thanks for your help!  Sorry if that's what you meant when you asked about auto-layout.  Thought you meant for the scroll view.

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant in my first comment. Glad you got it figured out. I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is usually because of translucent `UINavigationBar's`. Or Auto-Layout sometimes does this automatically based on the positioning of your Views and `UIScrollView`.

### SOLUTIONS:

1. The easiest thing to do is to disable Auto-Layout (it'll fix the problem in either situation) *OR* you can turn off translucency in your `UINavigationBar` if you don't need it.
2. If you need both of those things and you cannot sacrifice either, then use `contentInsets` to "un-offset" the offset. (this solution is considered very hacky and dirty)

Comment: Google is your friend, really?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep AutoLayout on, you should set your ScrollView `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.